# Sum of variabels from each for loop iterations

Tags: arrays, for-loop, variables, sum, codewarrior

I want to solve this exercise https://www.codewars.com/kata/5648b12ce68d9daa6b000099/train/python
[image]

How can I count result of count variable from first and second loop together ?
Result from first loop is 4-2 = 2, now I want sum of the 2 + result from second loop 10-6= 4. So the total sum should be 6 . Thanks for your tips :)

```
array =[(4,2), (10,6)]
print((array))
print(array[1])

for x in array:
    count = (x[0] - x[1])
    print (count)
```

I am not sure if this process is good for the exercise but I want it try this way :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

your approach doesn't look too bad. Iterating over the bus stop to find the difference of people leaving and joining the bus. You only have to add one variable that adds up these differences. I called it `counter`, which counts the current number of people on the bus. It starts with a value of zero. Then in each iteration, we add the difference to the `counter` variable. If more people leave the bus than enter it the `counter` will be decreased as `current_difference` is negative.
Here is an example implementation:

```
array =[(4,2), (10,6)]

counter = 0
for x in array:
    current_difference = (x[0] - x[1])
    print (current_difference)
    counter = counter + current_difference
    
print(counter)
```

Result:

```
6
```

Comment: Hi Jano,thanks very much this explanation is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: You`re welcome!